Identifying a plastic-like coating on an old record player
Could someone please help (1) identify what coating or covering this is and also (2) what causes this peeling and cracking to happen?
It is a slightly transparent like coating as seen in picture. It is like plastic in that it's slightly flexible and bendy.
It's from an old record player. Unfortunately I'm only allowed one picture.


Welcome to WSE. You can add more than one photo.  Opt to edit your post and add it in.

Additional hints might help. Was this an original manufacturer's finish.  Any idea what year it was?  If no idea on the approximate year, is there any kind of date, model number of manufacture name?  Other things that might help with age - is it electrified?  As record players go, what speed records does it handle 33,45 or 78?  If it is electrified, does it have vacuum tubes?  These answers may help in identifying it's age which then might be of help suggesting what finishes may have been typical at that time.

If this is merely a transparent clear coating then it's fairly likely to be nitrocellulose lacquer, because for most of the time record players were made lacquer was the commercial finish of choice. But the photo isn't clear enough to tell something for sure, is there a wood-grain pattern in this or just some minor thickness variation from the 3D grain of the wood it was originally bonded to? The cracking and peeling thing is easy to answer, whatever this is simply became more brittle over time, and in addition to natural age-related embrittlement some damage from light may also have occurred.
